# To stab in a downwards motion

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was wondering what the word was for “to stab in a downwards motion”. As in shanking downwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single word to define, "stabbing in a downward motion".

"Shanking", is slang for stabbing.

Depending on how you intend to use the word or phrase, you might to refer to the grip used to imply the motion.  For example, "he whirled around, holding the kinfe in an *icepick grip*, before stabbing the blade into the wooden counter surface".

There is knife fighting information on Wikipedia (as well as other sources). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_fight which describe various grips, techniques and phrases used with knives.